# How the Azimuthal quantum number describes 3d shape of the orbital?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I read yesterday that Azimuthal Quantum number describes the shape of orbital....

Answer (score 1):

what they call 'orbital' of an electron in chemistry is called wave function in physics. It determines how the electron moves and how it behaves. In fact it determines everything of the electrons. The azimuthal quantum number is just the quantum number used to describe angular part of the wave function, so it determines the shape of the orbital. This is a very rough explanation. You need to learn something like quantum chemistry or quantum mechanics in order to get a better understanding on that.

Comment: An orbital is not just a wavefunction, is a one-electron wavefunction, and for many-electron systems has no physical meaning.

Comment: Yes, but that is a long story for a beginner to understand. And as you said for many-electron systems has no physical meaning. In many-body case, we use the occupation of each states.

Comment: Yes, But how exactly numbers are related?

Comment: Have you ever learnt linear algebra? That would be of a lot of help to understand it.